# How do I get the child element of a css element?

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, capybara, rubymine

I am using Ruby with Selenium and have some code that grabs three elements. I want to get each one individually based on the order they are in. However, my terminal is not recognizing the :nth-child command, any suggestions?

```
def verify(order, name)
   :nth-child(order) do
      within ".css-element" do
        should_be_visible name
      end
   end
end
```

I see this error in my terminal:

> ```
>  NoMethodError:
> ```

```
   undefined method `child' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups>
```

Comment: Are you using pure selenium or capybara? If you are using capybara , please include that tag.

Comment: Thank you! I am using Capybara, forgot to add that in there.

Comment: I'm curious where you got the idea you could just call a random CSS selector in ruby? What exactly is `order`? Are you trying to find the `nth-child` of the `order` element? What is the value of `n` for nth, etc.  Please give more specifics of what exactly you're trying to do. Possibly show example HTML

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this and it worked!

```
def verify(order, name)
  within ".css-element:nth-child(#{order})" do
    should_be_visible name
  end
end
```